# Why is Spring not wiring my @Autowired members in a dependent jar?

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, ioc-container

I'm building a Google App Engine app using Spring 3.1 and am having a problem getting members in one of my jars wired.

I have three projects:

1. `server`
2. `server.model`
3. `server.persistence`

I have an ant build script so that when my workspace builds, it creates jars for `server.model` and `server.persistence`, and puts them in the correct lib directory for the `server` project.

In `server`, I can autowire things from both `server.model` and `server.persistence`, but in `server.model` my `server.persistence` beans aren't getting wired even though they're the exact same as in `server`.

snippet from my servlet application config:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.impersonal.server"/>          

<bean autowire="byType" id="appEngineDataStore" class="com.impersonal.server.persistance.AppEngineDataStore"/>

<bean autowire="byType" id="userList" class="com.impersonal.server.model.UserList"/>
```

I have the following code in both the `server` project and the `server.model` project, and only the server one gets fulfilled.  Here's the one failing:

```
package com.impersonal.server.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.impersonal.server.persistance.AppEngineDataStore;
import com.impersonal.server.persistance.IDataStore;

public class UserList extends ArrayList<User>
{
    private UserList(){}

//this is always null, but the same line in a class in the other project works
private @Autowired AppEngineDataStore _dataStore;

public UserList(UUID userId, String tempId)
{
    String poo = "poo";
    poo.concat("foo ");

    int i = 3;
}
}
```

**Edit:**
Just did a test in the `server.model` project trying to @Autowired something that I don't have defined as a bean in my application config, and didn't get any errors.  I should have got a 'no such bean found' error like I do if I do the same thing for the `server` project.

Any ideas why?

Comment: They are from the same package `<context:component-scan base-package="com.impersonal.server"/>  `?

Comment: @JigarJoshi yes.  The failing class is in package com.impersonal.server.model

Comment: Could be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564044/spring-qualifier-not-working-when-bean-is-in-another-jar-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was instantiating my objects incorrectly.  For framework objects and such like MVC controllers, you don't need to do anything to get your @Autowired members wired.

For objects I was creating on the fly, I wasn't going through the IOC container, that's why their dependencies weren't being fulfilled.

Comment: can you provide more details on how you solved this?

Comment: he meant that if you create an object using "new", it will not be autowired.

Answer (score 1):

`<context:component-scan/>` tag searches for annotated classes.

If you are going to autowire class using `@Autowire` annotation, Autowiring class should be annotated with one of stereotype annotation (@Component,@Controller,@Service,@Repository). Spring resolves first annotation configuration and then xml configuration. This is written in spring doc as

> Annotation injection is performed before XML injection, thus the latter configuration will override the former for properties wired through both approaches.

Check proof on [spring doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-annotation-config).

So what you need to do is add annotations for classes from `server` project as well as `server.model`. Same in case of your third project `server.persistence`. Add annotations according to layers or functionality.

Comment: I interpreted the documentation differently, but you may be on to something.  I created a new class in server with no class level annotation, and it's not Autowiring it's members.

Comment: @MStodd : that's what I am saying. And that is why I told you to add stereotype annotations (@Component,@Controller,@Service,@Repository) depending on functionality of the class

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@Autowired(required = true)
private AppEngineDataStore _dataStore;
```

Instead of:

```
private @Autowired AppEngineDataStore _dataStore;
```

**EDIT 1:**

While using the autowire above, in your spring xml, try:

```
<bean id="appEngineDataStore" class="com.impersonal.server.persistance.AppEngineDataStore" scope="prototype"></bean>
```

Instead of:

```
<bean autowire="byType" id="appEngineDataStore" class="com.impersonal.server.persistance.AppEngineDataStore"/>
```

Comment: the problem isn't how it's defined, spring isn't even looking at the code in this project for @Autowired members.  See question edit

Answer (score 0):

`autowire` in xml means slightly different thing. Instead of defining your bean in xml, you can annotate it as `@Service`, it will be discovered by the component-scan and the `@Autowired` will work.

Comment: I don't think spring is even scanning my jar, which is the problem.  I can try your suggestion, but if I Autowired a bogus bean in server.model, it runs fine.  If I Autowired a bugus bean in server, I get an error because spring attempts to resolve it and can't.

Answer (score 0):

In your xml configuration, use `autowire-candidate` property

```
<bean autowire="byType" id="appEngineDataStore" class="com.impersonal.server.persistance.AppEngineDataStore" autowire-candidate="true" />
```